# How to get Substring in sql query

Tags: sql, substring, dbeaver

I am trying to get substring from 0-7 position in an int element in table name so when I insert this

```
select substring(column_name,0, 6) as new_name from table_name
```

I am getting

> SQL Error [42883]: ERROR: function pg_catalog.substring(bigint,
>   integer, integer) does not exist
>
> Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You
>   might need to add explicit type casts.
>
> Position: 8
>
> org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: function
>   pg_catalog.substring(bigint, integer, integer) does not exist
>
> Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You
>   might need to add explicit type casts.   Position: 8

so after adding some cast to varchar(8)

```
select substring(varchar(8),column_name,0, 6) as new_name from table_name
```

getting this

> SQL Error [42601]: ERROR: syntax error at or near ","   Position: 28
>   org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "," 
>   Position: 28

I cant figure out what am I doing wrong. Thanks.

Comment: Functions are not standardised, every database can have different, and usually have. Your tagging say about dbeaver and not postgres

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can `cast` the `int` column as `varchar` and then make a `substring` from `1` to `7`

```
select substring(cast([your-column] as varchar(100)),1, 7)
```

Example:

```
  declare @a int ='1234567890';
  select substring(cast(@a as varchar(100)),1, 7) as res
```

Output :

```
  res 
  1234567
```

Comment: Thank you ser, the @ was what I was missing.

Comment: You can use the len(column) function in case you need to pass the length as the third parameter.

Answer (score 3):

Cast directly to text:

```
select substring(column_name::text, 1, 7) as new_name
from table_name
```

Note that SQL (unlike C-like languages) uses *1-based* indexing, so the first character is position `1`. Also unlike C-like languages, the second parameter of substring is the *length* (not the exclusive end index).